# How to use CSS to create a slider?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slideshow

I have downloaded a theme for my webpage which has a slider in it. but the slider is not working. I have tried to use bootstrap to create a  slideshow. but when i refer the bootstrap.css with this html the style breaks. How can I create a slide show with this code with CSS?

I don't want to use events like javascript onclick. I am still a learner.

This is my HTML code for slide show block.

```
<ul class="home-slider slick-initialized slick-slider">

        <div style="opacity: 1; width: 9515px;">


            <li class="slick-slide"  style="width: 1903px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 750ms ease;">

                <div class="image-caption"> <img class="desktop-img" src="images/slider-1.jpg"> </div>

                         </li>
             <li class="slick-slide"  style="width: 1903px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 750ms ease;">

                <div class="image-caption"> <img class="desktop-img" src="images/slider-2.jpg"> </div>

                         </li>
            <li class="slick-slide"  style="width: 1903px; position: relative; left: -7612px;; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1; transition: opacity 750ms ease;">

                <div class="image-caption"> <img class="desktop-img" src="images/slider-3.jpg"> </div>

                         </li>

        </div>  
        <ul class="slick-dots" style="display: block;" role="tablist">  
            <li><button type="button"  tabindex="0">1</button></li> 
            <li><button type="button" tabindex="0">2</button></li>  
            <li><button type="button"  tabindex="0">3</button></li>

        </ul>

</ul>
```

and this is the css.

```
.home-slider {position: relative;}
.home-slider {width: 100%;float: left;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
.home-slider li.slick-slide {width: 100%;float: left;position: relative;}

.home-slider ul.slick-dots {bottom: 32px;margin: 0px;width: auto;float: right;right: 0px;padding-right: 52px;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots li {margin: 0 8px;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots li button {width: 25px;height: 25px;display: inline-block;border: 5px solid #fff;border-radius: 50%;background: #fff;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots button:before {display: none;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots li.slick-active button {border-color: #f5be18;background: transparent;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots li button {width: 15px;height: 15px;}
.home-slider ul.slick-dots {bottom: 10px;}
.slick-slide {float: left;height: 100%;min-height: 1px;display: none;}
.slick-slide img {display: block;}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img {display: none;}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {display: block;}
.slick-loading .slick-slide {visibility: hidden;}
.slick-slider .slick-list, .slick-track, .slick-slide, .slick-slide img {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);-moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);-ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);-o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);}
```

This are the stylesheets reference in my html

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/ModuleStyleSheets.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Box.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Comment: Your CSS looks copied from Slick slider. Why not just using Slick? It’s great.

Comment: How to do it with this stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css files respect a hierarchy, so you need to call the files by precedence, from the "least important" to the "most important", as you have already done if the bootstrap file is conflicting, just change the order of the call , that is:

**style bootstrap**

**style slick-slider**

and the most important thing is that your main site style (main.css, style.css) has to be the last file to be imported into the code.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Why just not use the original [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) slider. You will need to modify your markup, and add some css and js links as well. Check my snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<div class="home-slider">
  <div class="image-caption">
    <img class="desktop-img" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-caption">
    <img class="desktop-img" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="image-caption">
    <img class="desktop-img" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz3.png">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.home-slider').slick({
      dots : true,
      arrows : false
    });
  });
</script>
```

**Some considerations:**

- Read the [documentation](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), so you can adjust the slider according to your needs
- Modify `slick-theme.css` to you needs (make sure you download that file) modify it the way you want (i included the linked one just for the snippet to work)